# Missing endpoints in WSO2

Tags: wso2

Does the WSO2 provide endpoints like Schemas and ServiceProviderConfigs
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Schemas
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/ServiceProviderConfigs

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 exposes SCIM endpoints in its Identity Server.

However, if you look into the service definition (and WSO2's documentation), you will find that only two services are defined: **Users** and **Groups**

You can still go to Carbon and add Service Probider and Schemas in there, just not through SCIM's REST API.